# Ckeditor5 conversion - wrapping image into a link

Tags: data-conversion, ckeditor5, downcast

I am trying to implement a simple ckeditor conversion to wrap my image into an `<a>` tag.

```
editor.conversion.for('downcast').add(dispatcher => {
    dispatcher.on('insert:imageBlock', (evt, data, conversionApi) => {
        const viewImage = viewWriter.createAttributeElement('img');
        const insertPosition = conversionApi.mapper.toViewPosition(data.range.start);

        conversionApi.mapper.bindElements(data.item, viewImage);
        viewWriter.insert(insertPosition, viewImage);

        evt.stop();
    });
});
```

The base "insert:imageBlock" creates a `<figure>` element with an `<img>` inside, the code above removes the figure and only binds the imageBlock model to my newly created `<img>` tag and it works fine.

But I cannot find a solution to wrap that newly created `<img>` tag into an `<a>` tag with my desirable `href`.

Does anyone know a simple solution to this?

Thanks!